# Integrate Google API with C#

Tags: c#

Please help me how do I fix the redirect URL in google API. See this screenshot:

[image]

I added Authorized JavaScript origins and Authorized redirect URIs but it's not working:

[image]

I would appreciate it if you helped me out with this.

[image]

Sorry for my ignorance

Thanks,
LamNV11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to solve the localhost issue with an OAuth provider is to use a service like `http://vcap.me/` which [resolves to 127.0.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562954/public-wildcard-domain-name-to-resolve-to-127-0-0-1) no matter what subdomain you use.

So add `http://my-domain-name-goes-here.vcap.me/` to your Google OAuth settings and use that instead.

Note: `127.0.0.1` is not the same as `localhost` as far as an OAuth provider like Google is concerned and some OAuth providers don't allow localhost. Using vcap.me or one of the others solves this problem.

Comment: Sorry i until understand it. Could i must add : http://localhost:xxx.vcap.me in redirect url ?

Comment: @NguyenLam you would put `http://xxx.vcap.me` or `https://xxx.vcap.me` in the redirect url and no matter what `xxx` is it will resolve to 127.0.0.1 through DNS.