# How to achieve subdomain type domain names with php

Tags: php

I am developing a site where users will have permalinks for them like **user.domain.com** or **domain.com/user** and i want to achieve this by php code. foe ex.
for username **stack** the permalink is *stack* and on going to **stack.domain.com** or **domain.com/stack** it should go to profile page of user!

Comment: This is not a task for PHP alone. What server environment are you on?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79764/wildcard-subdomains

Comment: stack.domain.com will be at dns side you need to setup subdomain yeah domain.com/stack this could be possible with php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's split the two cases:

### user.domain.com

For this to work, you should first configure your DNS so that *.domain.com points to your server. Then in index.php, you can check if `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` matches something.domain.com (using e.g. [preg_match](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)). After verifying `something` is a valid username, you can either display the user's profile page or redirect to the profile.

**Caution**: make sure that any subdomain you use yourself, like for example `www.`, is not a valid username.

### domain.com/user

To implement this, you need to setup some kind of catch-all for non-existing pages. One way would be to instruct your webserver to serve a php-file when it encounters a 404. This file could then use the `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` variable to determin if there if a user profile is requested.

**Caution**: Make sure that any `/something` that is already a valid page is not a valid username. Alternatively you could use a prefix like `domain.com/u/user` to be more flexible in the names of your own pages.

Answer (score 1):

you should check if your webserver has those "wildcards", then you could achive this by writting a magic virutal host witch will handle that.

try a virtual host like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName local
ServerAlias *.local
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%1/public_html
UseCanonicalName Off
</VirtualHost>
```

source: http://neziric.org/2010/06/dynamic-apache-vhosts-2/

Comment: I have bought the server space. So this virtual host configuration of apache cant help. one and only way is to do it by my site itself.