# Wildcard Subdomain in Wordpress for every user that sign up

Tags: wordpress, wildcard-subdomain

I want to assign a subdomain for every user that sign up in my wordpress site. E.g.

For user **john**:

```
john.example.com
```

For user **Mark**:

```
mark.example.com
```

And I want to do that from wordpress side. Not from server side or any other.

Comment: What do you mean "not from server side"? Wordpress **is** running server-side. And what do you want to have at that subdomain?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wildcard Subdomains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79764/wildcard-subdomains)

Comment: I don't want to do that from Apache side. Like not with .htaccess. I want to do that from CMS side.

Comment: Do you want a simple redirect to an URL or something else?

Comment: I want to change all of the link respect to the subdomain. Like: After user John sign up:  www.example.com/shop will change to: john.example.com/shop