# WordPress multisite setup as subdomain - wildcard DNS record setup

Tags: wordpress, dns, multisite

I am new to WP multisite environment. I want to setup multisite in my local Ubuntu 14.04 environment. I already have localhost for my main site configured as carbazarlocal.com and its running OK. When I go to **Tools > Network Setup** I can see two options - Sub-domain and Sub-directory. I want to setup my multisites as sub-domains like dealer1.carbazarlocal.com, dealer2.carbazarlocal.com etc.

On this page WordPress says **"You will need a wildcard DNS record if you are going to use the virtual host (sub-domain) functionality"**. How to do this and where?

### In /etc/hosts I have the following entry:

```
127.0.0.1   carbazarlocal.com
```

### In /etc/apache2/apache2.conf I have the following:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/carbazar>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

### In /etc/apache2/sites-available/carbazarlocal.com.conf I have this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin admin@carbazarlocal.com
     ServerName carbazarlocal.com
     ServerAlias *.carbazarlocal.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/carbazar
</VirtualHost>
```

### And in /var/www/html/carbazar/wp-config I have this:

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
```

What else I need to do and where to complete the following step:
"You will need a wildcard DNS record if you are going to use the virtual host (sub-domain) functionality"?

Comment: Hey ! did you manage to find any solution ? :')

Answer (score 1):

If you use Apache server then ...

In the httpd.conf file, or in the include file containing the VirtualHost section for your web account, add a line like this (if it is not already present):

`ServerAlias *.example.com`

Also create a wildcard DNS record like:

`*.example.com A 192.0.43.10`

> REF https://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Wildcard_Subdomains